# SQL Server Query Join Across Servers Only Works With WHERE Statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a bizzare query problem.
I have a script developed in AS400/Iseries SQL which I needed to duplicate to an SQL Server.   One of the steps needs me to join from a work table on SQL Server to a table on the linked server AS400/Iseries.

So I run this on the SQL Server against a local table ROWS01 and the linked server AS400/Iseries table, SBWWEP.

Returns Nothing:-

```
SELECT R.Company, 
       G.Company, 
       R.GRN, 
       G.GRN,

FROM [SQLDBase].dbo.ROWS01 R INNER JOIN AS400.ISERIES.LIBRARY1.SBWWEP G
           ON  R.Company = G.Company AND
               R.GRN     = G.GRN

WHERE R.Pos_Type = '2-GRN Single';
```

It returns no rows on SQL Server but the original AS400/Iseries script performing the same task returns lots.

I fiddled about a bit and found that the join doesn’t work on SQL Server unless I put a literal in the WHERE condition. Why is this???

Returns Lots Of Rows:-

```
SELECT R.Company, 
       G.Company, 
       R.GRN, 
       G.GRN,

FROM [SQLDBase].dbo.ROWS01 R INNER JOIN AS400.ISERIES.LIBRARY1.SBWWEP G
       ON  R.Company = G.Company AND
           R.GRN     = G.GRN

WHERE R.Pos_Type = '2-GRN Single';
AND   G.Company = '52' 
AND   G.Company > '000000';
```

Comment: probably the quotes make it serialize as charcter data going between the machines.